# Как реализовать на java (RestFull) подключение к стороннему сервису (API)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

Дорогие форумчане, поделитесь опытом - как реализовать подключение стороннего сервиса (API-ссылки есть) на основе Java Spring Boot? Мое серверное приложение в итоге должно выступать в роли посредника (агрегатора).Проблема в следующем - я знаю, как возвращать html страницу, JPA, но не представляю (Google не помог), как предоставить клиенту через Get-запрос сервис стороннего сайта, например курс валют, карту, погоду и т.д.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Вам нужно использовать HttpClient. Они есть разные. Есть и "штатный" спринговый. Почитайте https://attacomsian.com/blog/http-requests-resttemplate-spring-boot

Comment: Спасибо огромное, очень помогли.

Comment: Annotations `@RestController` или `@Controller`